# Whats purpose of four pole breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I was working on a friends house today, mostly running a new branch circuit for an upgraded kitchen.   That all went fine.   However, the panel in the basement has a four pole breaker as the main.  I've never seen a panel this way.  What's the purpose?

[image]

Has anybody seen this before?   Why would they do this?

Comment: Is that perhaps a 400A panel?

Comment: Technically it is not a "4 pole" as it does not take up 4 spaces in the panel. What you have there is a main breaker that is using two 200 Amp double pole with a single common trip. If you look closely at the two buss bars, you'll notice they split and give the illusion of 4 poles.

Comment: Dan, its a 200 amp.   And Kris, yes, its is akin to a 200 amp double double.   I guess I called it four pole because of the bar across the switches.  you can also see how they are connected at the load side.

Comment: @Dan D. That is a 200A main breaker, therefore the panel is only good for 200 Amps or less, not 400

Answer (score 11):

The manufacturer decided that rather than develop a 200 ampere double pole breaker, they'd parallel 100 ampere breakers to create the breaker instead.

Each leg of the service is connected to a pair of 100 ampere single pole breakers in parallel. This configuration allows the current to be divided equally between the breakers, as long as it can be guaranteed that the resistance across each breaker is nearly identical.

Basically the manufacturer created a double pole 200 ampere breaker, using four 100 ampere breakers.

Before you get the idea to try this at home, 240.8 of the National Electrical Code (NEC) prohibits it.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 240 Overcurrent Protection
>
> **240.8 Fuses or Circuit Breakers in Parallel.** Fuses and circuit breakers shall be permitted to be connected in parallel where they are factory assembled in parallel and listed as a unit. Individual fuses, circuit breakers, or combinations thereof shall not otherwise be connected in parallel